# Converting a nested list of dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to convert a nested list of dictionary into a substructure. And finding a robust way to do so. The structure:

```
nested_list = [
  {
     "id" : "fruit",
     "name" : "apple"
  },
  {
     "name": "fruit"
  },
  {
     "id" : "fruit",
     "name" : "grape"
  },
  {
     "id" : "fruit",
     "name" : "pineapple"
  },
  {
     "name": "vehicle"
  },
  {
    "id" : "vehicle",
     "name": "car"
  },
  {
    "id" : "car",
     "name": "sedan"
  },
]
```

Into:

```
{
  "vehicle": {
    "car": {
        "sedan" : {}
     }
  },
  "fruit" : {
     "apple": {},
    "grape": {},
    "pineapple": {}
  }
}
```

Note that in this case it can go two level down. But It can go three deep down as well. For example one additional entry:

```
{ 
   "id" : "sedan", 
   "name": "mini sedan" 
}
```

My approach so far is:

```
for category in nested_list:
    if 'id' not in category:
        d[category['name']] = {}

for category in nested_list:
    if 'id' in category and category['id'] in d:
        d[category['id']][category['name']] = {}
    elif 'id' in category and category['id'] not in d:
        for k, v in d.items():
            if category['id'] in v:
                d[k][category['id']] = {category['name']: {}}
    # If there are not top level key then do nothing
    else:
        pass
```

It works in this case. The problem is it's not robust enough. I'm thinking recursion but unable to crack it. Can someone help out? Thank you

Comment: Hi, when you say "nested list", is that intentional? The list you provided is not nested. It contains dictionaries all at the same level.

Comment: Oh Im wrong. It's not nested list. But rather a strange structure with hierarchy

Comment: Can you share an example with problematic input ?

Comment: problematic input? The first list is the a potential input. I went to have a conversion function to return output like second dictionary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution

You can use `collections.defaultdict` and `dict.setdefault`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

nested_list = [
    {
        "id": "fruit",
        "name": "apple"
    },
    {
        "name": "fruit"
    },
    {
        "id": "fruit",
        "name": "grape"
    },
    {
        "id": "fruit",
        "name": "pineapple"
    },
    {
        "name": "vehicle"
    },
    {
        "id": "vehicle",
        "name": "car"
    },
    {
        "id": "car",
        "name": "sedan"
    },
    {
        "id": "sedan",
        "name": "mini sedan"
    },
]

working_dict = defaultdict(dict)
result_dict = {}

for item in nested_list:
    name = item['name']
    if 'id' in item:
        id_ = item['id']
        working_dict[id_].setdefault(name, working_dict[name])
    else:
        result_dict[name] = working_dict[name]
print(working_dict)
print(result_dict)
```

output:

```py
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'fruit': {'apple': {}, 'grape': {}, 'pineapple': {}}, 'apple': {}, 'grape': {}, 'pineapple': {}, 'vehicle': {'car': {'sedan': {'mini sedan': {}}}}, 'car': {'sedan': {'mini sedan': {}}}, 'sedan': {'mini sedan': {}}, 'mini sedan': {}})
{'fruit': {'apple': {}, 'grape': {}, 'pineapple': {}}, 'vehicle': {'car': {'sedan': {'mini sedan': {}}}}}
```

---

#### Explanation

- The idea: `dict` is mutable.
- `working_dict` is reference table for all `"id"`s.
- If there is no such id, register `{}` for it.
- And register elements without `id` field, as root elements into `result_dict`.

---

#### Append

If you don't want to use `collections.defaultdict`, you can only use `dict.setdefault`. But it is more verbose.

```py
working_dict = {}
result_dict = {}

for item in nested_list:
    name = item['name']
    if 'id' in item:
        id_ = item['id']
        working_dict.setdefault(id_, {}).setdefault(name, working_dict.setdefault(name, {}))
    else:
        result_dict[name] = working_dict.setdefault(name, {})
print(result_dict)
```

Comment: this is good. I thought using defaultdict as well. But I want a answer similar to:

{'fruit': {'apple': {}, 'grape': {}, 'pineapple': {}}, 'vehicle': {'car': {'sedan': {'mini sedan': {}}}}}

Comment: `result_dict` is it.

Comment: Oh wow that's amazing. Thank you so much. Just wondering is there a way for regular code this? If not or take too much time that's fine

Comment: I don't get what _regular code_ means. Can you explain more?

Comment: That means not using defaultdict

Comment: I appended for it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it manually with a recursive function. The idea:

- Iterate over the element in the input list
- Ignore element without `id` key
- For element with an `id` in keys:

  - recursively search for this key in the out
  - add the element (if element already existing, the element is add in the recursive function, else after).

```
# Recursive search
def iterdictAdd(d, id, name):
    # For all element in the dict
    for k, v in d.items():
        # If key match -> add
        if k == id:
            d[id] = {**d[id], **{name: {}}}
            return True
        else:
            # Recursive call
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                if iterdictAdd(v, id, name):
                    return True
    return False


out = {}
# Iterate all dict
for dict_ in nested_list:
    # Ignore elements without "id" 
    if "id" in dict_:
        # Search and add this key
        if not iterdictAdd(out, dict_["id"], dict_["name"]):
            out[dict_["id"]] = {dict_["name"]: {}}

print(out)
# {'fruit': {
#     'apple': {},
#     'grape': {},
#     'pineapple': {}
# },
#  'vehicle': {
#     'car': {
#         'sedan': {}
#         }
#     }
# }
```